# How to use the '?' on a QDialog window tile bar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

With a window generated by a QDialog with QT Designer there is a '?' button on the window title bar.  How do you connect this button to a html file that displays help information?  I expected that there would be an object within QT Designer that references the '?' button, but, I can't locate it.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *How do you connect this button to a html file that displays help information*?

Comment: I have a QDialog and I wanted to show some information that explains how to use the QDialog (a help file).  My understanding is that the most common approach for creating a help file is to place the help information in a html file.  I thought that the '?' button on the title bar of a QDialog could be used for this purpose but I couldn't find documentation on what the '?' button is for.  Maybe it is better to use a QMainWindow instead of a QDialog?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you want to use the button, but if you want to detect the click event and assuming you are in Windows then a possible solution is to use the `nativeEvent()` method since that element depends on each platform:

```
import ctypes.wintypes
import win32con
from  PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message):
        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        if eventType == "windows_generic_MSG":
            if msg.message == win32con.WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
                print("Hello World")
        return super(Dialog, self).nativeEvent(eventType, message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.exec_()
```